# Python all lists of list of integers with exact summary

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic, summary, sublist

I need a help with an algorithm that takes a list of integers and value and finds all lists that add up to value. Fore example : fn ([1,1,2,2,3],4) -> [[1,1,2],[1,3],[2,2]]

It must be an recursive soulution without added libraries.
I have spent a lot of time figuring this out, but so far I have nothing.

Appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Generate all possible combinations of that list and check which of those combinations add up to the target value.

Comment: I would suggest you check out this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-combinations-of-distinct-numbers-which-add-up-to-give-sum-n/) in geeksforgeeks and read more about knapsack problem.

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a place where people do all your work for you. See: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I need to have 50 reputation to comment above, so posting here. 
**Kindly do not consider this as an answer.**

> *Generate all possible combinations of that list and check which of those combinations add up to the target value.* As said by Selcuk above...

To generate all possible combinations of a list -

```
from itertools import combinations 
def mySubset(arr, r): 
    return list(combinations(arr, r)) 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
    r = 3
for x in arr:
  print(mySubset(arr, x))
```

It gives following result-

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]                                                                                                               
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]                                                                                       
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]                                                                                           
[(1, 2, 3, 4)]
```